# Baixando emails do Mailchimp

Tags: php

Boa tarde

Estou fazendo uma integração do Mailchimp com PHP e preciso baixar do Mailchimp os emails que estão como "unsubscribed" e "cleaned" para atualizar no banco.

Atualmente não há um controle muito fiel de Campanhas, Segmentos e Listas (no Mailchimp só tem uma lista enorme de emails e para enviar uma campanha, ela geralmente é criada diretamente no Mailchimp, enviando emails para uma lista à partir de um arquivo .csv), por isso para eu gerar uma lista de envio, preciso filtrar esses erros para que um contato que tenha se descadastrado não receba nenhum email.

Tem alguma função da API ou algum meio que eu possa baixar só esses emails para o meu banco?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri como baixar os emails. É necessário usar a biblioteca CURL para acessar a versão 3.0 da API que o Mailchimp disponibiliza. Segue abaixo um exemplo:

```
$apikey = 'sua_api_key';
$listid = 'sua_list_id';
$server = 'seu_server.';
$auth = base64_encode( 'user:'.$apikey );
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://'.$server.'api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/'.$listid.'/members/?status=unsubscribed');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('content-type: application/json', 'Authorization: Basic '.$auth));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP-MCAPI/2.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_post);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
```

Desse jeito, toda a informação necessária vai vir em formato json, daí é só transformar em objeto e trabalhar no resultado. O único problema é que o result set só retorna 10 resultados.

Comment: "É necessário usar a biblioteca CURL" - Eu acredito que usar cURL seja uma de diversas maneiras, e não "necessário".

Comment: Bom, certamente... me expressei mal rs